# Keyed access through OPNQRYF

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a non-keyed physical file (say X) and I want to access it according to a key.I have used OPNQRYF with KEYFLD parameter and shared it's ODP.In rpgle program i am opening file X in arrival sequence(i.e not specifying K on F specs).Does the rpg program will process the records according to the key or in arriving sequence? Also I am facing a strange error when I am doing

```
Setll 1 XR
read XR
```

Consider XR as record format of file X.It is skipping the first record and reading from second record onward.

Answer (score 2):

If your file is not keyed, it will read in arrival sequence.

For the SETLL, try

`SETLL *LOVAL XR`

That should position right before the first record.

If you want to access the file via key, create a view or Logical File over it with the key you want.  Then be sure to specify it in the F spec as a keyed file.  Or just use SQL to retrieve the records with ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Suggested in the OP, is that the program is reading from the shared Open Data Path (ODP) that was defined\created with a keyed access path via the Open Query File (OPNQRYF), apparently per specifying field name(s) on the Key Field (KEYFLD) parameter. What matters, is the ODP, rather than if\that the "file is not keyed".  FWiW to position to the *first* record, use `SETLL *START X`. FWiW a VIEW can not be keyed [except when used to create a query ODP]; the SQL equivalent of a keyed LF is the [binary radix] INDEX.

Comment: I don't recall the OPNQRYF being in the original question.. either that or it I was low on coffee.  Or haven't seen an OPNQRYF for so long I read right over it.. haha.. Thanks for the comment, Charles.